# Google Search Console Security Issues message, but no other details

Tags: google, google-search-console

Today I got security warning in the Google Search Console that there are health issues in my site. When I click on the message though there is no other details. Also, when I go into the property under Security Issues, there is nothing in it. 
What does it mean? Thoughts?

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of the message?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your website was hacked and some malware put on it. Check HTML source of your website pages for something you didn't put there. 
There is useful help on this topic from Google. Check out this link: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/hacked/docs/hacked_with_malware?hl=en